# create safe title from string

Tags: jquery, url, preg-replace

moving a lot more of my old php functions to jquery alternatives. I'm a bit stuck on creating a decent preg_match function.

Is there an easy way to make strings url safe & seo'd?

php;

```
function superClean($str){

$str = strtolower($str);
$str = str_replace(" ", "-", $str);
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]/i', '-', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/_[_]*/i', '-', $str);
$str = str_replace('---', '-', $str);
$str = str_replace('--', '-', $str);
$str = str_replace('-s-', 's-', $str);

return $str;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with JavaScript's regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wow - never used them that much but think they're gonna be really useful for the future!

```
var String = "My'New ?! 'æ î Hat";
var string = String.toLowerCase();
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g,'-');
alert(string.replace(/[-]{2,}/,'-'))
```

thanks Jan!